# how to chop out an ipaddress from a packet using java

Tags: java

"i have packet format(srcIP,destIP,protocol number,frame length)in files like this in a file.i need to get only scrIP.

49.112.250.206,0.217.206.74,17,1458 25.82.23.122,211.231.164.237,6,46 218.55.186.252,211.231.171.101,6,46 36.63.70.74,73.151.138.2,6,1504 232.60.178.64,78.217.241.214,6,1504 181.175.235.118,58.57.101.205,6,1504
133.203.23.94,74.110.251.121,6,1504
......
......"

```
for (List<String> read : readFiles.values())
    {       
        while(last>=0)
        {
            last=1;
            String element=read.get(first);
            StringTokenizer st=new StringTokenizer(element, ",");
            //int token=Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken(","));

            first++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of `StringTokenizer` use `String#split()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String tmp[]=element.split(" "); //get one by one

for(String s:tmp) {
    System.out.println(s.split(",")[0]); //get only srcIP
}
```